# Repeatable background method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I've been looking all over the place for a way to do this with no success.
I'm doing an MVC5 project.
I'm trying to get a method that does something particular, **to run in the background of my program repeatably every 10 mins** (The method gets info from other sites and puts them in the DB).

I would love some examples via links, or some directions to do it in an efficient way.

Comment: You should run this as a separeted Windows Service on your host.

Comment: ...or make a little .exe and run a Scheduled Task.

Comment: Where do you deploy your app? Azure? On premise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great idea to try and tie up an IIS thread like this for background work. A better option is to have a separate process do the work e.g. Windows Service. However, if you're constrained in the options you can use maybe:

- Create simple console app to do the work, and set up a Windows Scheduled Task to run it at the 10 minute interval. (This assumes that you can do that in your deployment setup)
- If all else fails, create a normal action method on a controller that does the task. The task will execute when the url is hit ... so hit that url every 10 minutes via a CRON job (often provided by your hosting provider).

Not your typical options, but I get the feeling they may be practical for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a timed event.

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(600,000);
timer.elapsed += (sender, e) => { /*fetch data*/ };
```

Comment: And that will work well until the process gets recycled from the IIS runtime just in the middle of that. Great tip.